# Is it possible to undefine or replace the existing enum?

Tags: enums, mql5

For example there is a [`ENUM_INDICATOR`](https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/indicatorconstants/enum_indicator) type which I'd like to undefine and replace with my own, e.g.

```
#undef ENUM_INDICATOR
#undef IND_AC
#undef IND_AD
#undef IND_AC
#ifndef ENUM_INDICATOR
enum ENUM_INDICATOR {
  IND_AC,
  IND_AD,
  IND_NONE,
}
#endif
```

However none of above works, because compiler complains as below:

> 'ENUM_INDICATOR' - enumeration already defined
>
> 'IND_AC' - enumerator identifier already defined

Is there any chance to undefine or remove the existing builtin enum types?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to undefine the existing enum declaration or its items.

<sup>Source: Response from Support Team at MQL5.</sup>